# I've got this error: Uncaught TypeError: e.lngLat is not a function or its return value is not iterable at handleAddClick (App.js:42:1)

Tags: reactjs, appjs

```
const handleAddClick = (e) =>{   
const [lat, long] =  e.lngLat;<=errr
setNewPlace({lat,long
     });
  };
```

I want to create an event when I click in a new place  to extract the latitude and longitude and to display the result in a popup.

```
console.log(e.lngLat)
Po {lng: 21.940196455078166, lat: 47.07052843855962}
lat: 47.07052843855962
lng: 21.940196455078166
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: class Po
distanceTo: ƒ distanceTo(t)
toArray: ƒ toArray()
toBounds: ƒ toBounds()
toString: ƒ toString()
wrap: ƒ wrap()
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Do `console.log(e.lngLat)` & insert them into your question.

Comment: Po
lat: 47.06982692505099
lng: 21.953414381103244
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: class Po
distanceTo: ƒ distanceTo(t)
toArray: ƒ toArray()
toBounds: ƒ toBounds()
toString: ƒ toString()
wrap: ƒ wrap()
[[Prototype]]: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [object-destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) instead of array.

```
const { lat, lng: long } = e.lngLat;

const handleAddClick = (e) => {
  const [lat, long] = e.lngLat;
  setNewPlace({ lat, long });
};
```